# Really no way to disable those keytips in Windows 10 ? (holding ALT)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, user-interface

[image: nasty keytips]

**Is there really no way to disable these annoying tips in the 'file explorer' on Windows 10???**

I remember having seen a setting somewhere, but maybe this was back in windows 7, maybe in some tweaking tool.

Searching the web for a long time did not lead to anything.

Comment: I would imagine that tweaking tool has been updated to support Windows 10.  You would indeed need third-party software to disable that particular feature.

Comment: This page from BRINK at "Ten Forums" may help you, I'm not sure: "Turn On or Off Underline Access Key Shortcuts in Menus in Windows 10" https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/97413-turn-off-underline-access-key-shortcuts-menus-windows-10-a.html